# Reverse Engineering a Database to Entity Framework Code First Classes with Inheritance

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

When I reverse Engineer a Database using Entity Framework Power Tools, I would like one to one relationships to come across as inherited classes. How do I achieve this?
Cheers.